# Feedly not updating items in Craigslist RSS feed

Tags: rss, feeds, rss-reader

A few months ago, I set up a few Craigslist search feeds inside my Feedly. The feeds are frozen in time to that moment that I first set them up. No new results have ever come in through feedly.com. I am using the website. I dont have any apps on any platforms for Feedly.

If I try to create a new feed in feedly.com for one of these old searches, it says that I already have that feed. If I remove the old feed an resubscribe, the feed still contains the old data.

Countless webpages say that I should be able to use CL and Feedly together but that doesnt seem to be the case for me. Is this a problem with Feedly caching the content? How do I get Feedly to refresh the feed content?

**Current RSS feed for "gas grill"** Most recent post: March 8 2018
[image]

**Current screen in Feedly** Most recent post: Oct 5 2017
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Petr from Feedly.
This is, unfortunately, something we experience often with Craigslist. We are still in attempts to resolve this with Craigslist directly at the moment, unfortunately, they are a very difficult entity to communicate with. What happens is that we have to poll for new articles to their servers and since there are so many users of Feedly and so many requests for their servers, they blacklist us or limit the request we can ask per hour, day etc.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the update!

Comment: I'm having same problem. Even if you use feedburner they will ban Google's ips. their rss feeds are virtually useless unless you subscribe to just one.